# Redis is having very high fragmentation ratio

Tags: redis

My Redis cluster architecture is running with high fragmentation ratio upto 60. 
Is is good? What should be the ideal value ? What should I do get it normal?

the fragmentation ratio decrease during the working hours to as low as 2 while during non working hours it is as high as 50-60.

This issue is causing as we have put our log in / log out session state in redis. So there are frequent insert / delete in redis db.

Comment: Does it cause you any problems?

Comment: "What should I do get it normal?" - I suggest doing less inserts/deletes. :)

Comment: No, it don't cause any problem. But we are at initial level and only very less data going to redis. So I am very keen to understand the reason. Redis manage the login session state for us. So there will be insert/delete for every log in/log out.

Comment: maybe interesting? discussion about 'memory allocation' at the end of the page. http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization

Answer (score 3):

A fragmentation ratio greater than 1 indicates fragmentation is occurring. A ratio in excess of 1.5 indicates excessive fragmentation, with your Redis instance consuming 150% of the physical memory it requested. A fragmentation ratio below 1 tells you that Redis needs more memory than is available on your system, which leads to swapping. Swapping to disk will cause significant increases in latency (see used memory). Ideally, the operating system would allocate a contiguous segment in physical memory, with a fragmentation ratio equal to 1 or slightly greater.

If your server is suffering from a fragmentation ratio above 1.5, restarting your Redis instance will allow will allow the operating system to recover memory previously unusable due to fragmentation. In this case, an alert as a notification is probably sufficient.

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-monitor-redis-performance-metrics/

Comment: What if it's always above 3.0 even after a restart?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lua scripts, and have a small data set on the instance, `used_memory_lua` could be skewing this statistic, as it is not included in `used_memory`, but it *is* included in RSS, so the reported fragmentation ratio seems way too big.

See [this github issue](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2994) and see if your situation is similar.

You can clear cached lua scripts with the command `SCRIPT FLUSH`.

Comment: But I am not using Lua scripts.

Answer (score 0):

using command memory purge should help.

> The MEMORY PURGE command attempts to purge dirty pages so these can be reclaimed by the allocator.

This command is currently implemented only when using jemalloc as an allocator, and evaluates to a benign NOOP for all others.